# Code optimization in the Stochastic Schrödinger equation. Efficient matrix multiplication

Tags: optimization, julia, matrix-multiplication

I'm having a bottleneck in calculating the [Stochastic Schrödinger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199213909) (SSE) equation in Julia. The main bottlenecks of the algorithm are of course the time-step, which for me `10e-3` is enough but I need `tmax~200`; the number of realizations (`~100`); and the one that I would like to ask here: the amount of matrix-vector multiplications needed in each time step. Finally, for `Ntot=50` the program runs for around half an hour, but with  `300` it may well take around ten hours.

The main code that performs this computations is:

```
function avAPsi(Psi::Array{Complex128}, A::Array{Float64})
    return Psi'*A*Psi
end

function D1(gamma::Float64, Psi::Array{Complex128}, Htot::Array{Float64}, a_mat::Array{Float64}, term1::Complex128, number_operator::Array{Float64})                                                                           
    dummy = term1*a_mat - number_operator
    return -1im*Htot*Psi + 0.5*gamma*dummy*Psi - 0.125*gamma*term1^2*Psi
end

function D2(gamma::Float64, a_mat::Array{Float64}, term1::Complex128, Psi::Array{Complex128})
    return sqrt(gamma)*a_mat*Psi - 0.5*sqrt(gamma)*term1*Psi
end

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
delta_t = 0.001
wavef_t = Array{Complex128}(Ntot)
dummy = copy(wavef_t)
psiApsi = 0.0
for ii in 1:tsteps
     wavef_t[:] = 0.0
     DW = sqrt(delta_t)*randn()
     # Terms in Runge-Kutta                                                                                   
     psiApsi = avAPsi(init_st, A)
     Psi1 = D1(gamma1, init_st, Htot, a_mat, psiApsi, number_operator)
     dummy = init_st + 0.5*delta_t*Psi1
     psiApsi = avAPsi(dummy, A)
     Psi2 = D1(gamma1, dummy, Htot, a_mat, psiApsi, number_operator)
     dummy = init_st + 0.5*delta_t*Psi2
     psiApsi = avAPsi(dummy, A)
     Psi3 = D1(gamma1, dummy, Htot, a_mat, psiApsi, number_operator)
     dummy = init_st + delta_t*Psi3
     psiApsi = avAPsi(dummy, A)
     Psi4 = D1(gamma1, dummy, Htot, a_mat, psiApsi, number_operator)
     factor2 = D2(gamma1, a_mat, psiApsi, init_st)
     wavef_t = init_st + (1.0/6.0)*(Psi1 + 2.0*Psi2 + 2.0*Psi3 + Psi4)*delta_t + factor2*DW
     wavef_t = wavef_t/norm(wavef_t)                                                   
     init_st = copy(wavef_t)     
end # tsteps
```

So the algorithm for the SSE is essentially solving a stochastic differential
equation using 4th order Runge-Kutta. So in each time-step I have to compute
5-terms that contains matrix-vector multiplication. How one can improve this?

Comment: The very first thing you should do is to put your main loop inside a function, and avoid global variables. Have you read the performance tips in the Julia manual?

Comment: Yes I have read them. Yes this loop is in a function aside the main program.

Comment: Your code example cannot be run. Several of the variables you refer to are undefined. Can you please post a complete, self-contained code snippet, where you have also wrapped your main loop in a function? Also, you appear to be using an outdated version of Julia (you have some outdated code.) If you want better performance, and more useful help, you should be using an updated version of Julia. Currently, that is version 1.1.

Comment: Another thing: in `avAPsi` and `D1` most of the inputs are typed as simply `Array`. I think it would make you code easier to read and understand if you made it clear which inputs are vectors and which are matrices, instead of just generic arrays. Unless it unduly restricts your code, maybe you could use `Vector` and `Matrix` instead?

Comment: 4th order RK is really bad for SDEs (it's not actually 4th order, it's 0.5 order...). Why not use a more efficient method and chop off the number of steps or calls per step?

Comment: I'm not sure that it exists for the SSE (perhaps one can use every method designed for ODE, but since this is a stochastic equation, things may become subtle and I'm not sure how to proceed). On the other hand, I hope to catch someone who works with stochastic equations that could clarify this.

Comment: If I can just plug `TaylorSeries` package (which contains arbitrary precision) I would be very happy.

Comment: Have you checked out https://docs.juliadiffeq.org/latest/index.html ? They also have SDEs. They have lots of documentation, and a tutorial specifically for SDEs: https://docs.juliadiffeq.org/latest/tutorials/sde_example.html

Comment: You should really stop assuming calculus works on an SDE. TaylorSeries in the calculus sense do not converge on an SDE. SDE solutions are non-differentiable in the classical sense "almost everywhere" (all except a non-zero measure set with probability 1). There are higher order Runge-Kutta methods for SDEs implemented in DifferentialEquations.jl which take into account things like Ito-Taylor expansions for proper convergence. Any method designed for ODEs will not converge better than order 0.5 due to the lack of Levy area handling.

Comment: This was my first thought... I'm gonna check the package you suggested.

Comment: I also want to point out that the reference that I gave they claim that the Runge-Kutta (as I wrote it) is a valid approximation to the SSE.

Comment: It is valid to order 0.5, and so is Euler, so you might as well use Euler Maruyama if you don't want to use something specifically for SDEs.

Comment: Yes, I checked this and I was wrong. It is first order with some higher order correction for the part when noise is absent. Actually, there is another method which is second order weak scheme. Do you know if similar algorithms (of higher order) are given in the literature?